# How to make part of the Texture not to be scaled

Tags: textures, libgdx

I am new to LibGdx, i was doing one example for my learning and struck with this question, i had searched in google but i am not able to find the answer for this.

1) How to make part of the Texture not to be scaled.

[image: My Example image]

as you can see in the image i am reducing the height of bottom pipes so that the top pipe scale is reduced to fit the height given but i want the top part of the pipe not to be scaled.

in this example whole pipe is one texture, for fixing this problem i thought to split the top and body to separate texture and set height for only body but i thought there should be some other solution so that only i had put this question here.

2) my second question is not related to this problem , I want to know is there is any option in texture to keep on top of all other texture even after any new texture is added to screen.?

Comment: If I'm not wrong ninepatch is what you are looking for. Google it :p

Answer (score 0):

1) Looks to me that you are looking for 9 patch graphics, check this out:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/NinePatch.html

2) I think that textures are rendered one on top of all previously rendered so just render last the texture you want to appear on top.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two images:

Draw the top of the pipe not scaled and have another image that is the bottom of the pipe and scale only that.